how to support threadx module for risc v
I need use the theadx module feature in risc v platform, but the threadx module only support arm core now. I have studied the threadx module source code and riscv PMP. But it's still a diffcult thing to porting. Anyone have this experance to porting? or have some example code?
thanks
